# Daemonize a Python script on Raspbian Buster

Tags: python, daemon

I am working on an RFID-based access control system for which I have a working python script. For some specific details if they matter, the main processing is done on a pi zero w, which is connected by USB to a microcontroller that handles the input from the RFID module and sends it to the pi in string format for simplicity. The pi then compares the string received to a yaml file and a schedule and uses GPIO to switch on or off a door strike using a power supply. The issue I'm running into is that the script stops running after about 30 minutes, and I'm not quite sure why, but I think the ideal solution in any case is to daemonize it, because a cron job is too subject to failure and a daemon seems very appropriate for this use. Does anyone have any suggestions for daemonizing the script such that it will start on boot and restart itself if it detects a failure or that it is no longer running?

Comment: You should create [systemd unit](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/) to start and manage your script. This will allow you to have it start at boot and to have it automatically restarted if it should fail. You will find many guides on writing systemd units with some basic searching.

Answer (score 1):

As larsks said, you can create systemd service

`sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/yourscript.service`

This file should be something like this (read the [documentation](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) for more information):

```
[Unit]
Description=My cool script
After=multi-user.target

[Service]
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/path/to/your/script/directory/
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5s
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 your_script.py
StandardOutput=append:/var/log/your_script.log
StandardError=append:/var/log/your_script.log
SyslogIdentifier=coolawesomescript

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Then enable and start it:

```sh
foo@bar:~$ sudo systemctl enable yourscript
foo@bar:~$ sudo systemctl start yourscript
```

Now your script will automatically restart when it crashes

You can check if your script actually works by typing `sudo systemctl status yourscript`

Comment: I tried your solution, but I'm getting an exit code of 2 for invalid arguments, I think it has something to do with the parsing. Here is my execstart line: `ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 "/path/to/pyscript -k /path/to/configfile"` because my python script takes a command line argument. Is this supported, and if so how do I have the system parse it as a single token passed to python3 rather than three separate arguments (which I think is currently happening)? Thanks!

Comment: do not use quotation marks: `ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /path/to/pyscript -k /path/to/configfile`

Comment: Tried that first, it also did not work unfortunately with the same error code.

Comment: Then you can try something like `ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/python3 /path/to/pyscript -k /path/to/configfile"`